# Distributed TensorFlow: Create a session in only one worker to print the results

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just need to print the values of some global variables assigned within training. After closing the 'MonitoredTrainingSession', I created a session in the chief worker only using:

> ```
>     if FLAGS.task_index == 0:
>         with tf.Session() as sess:
>             print sess.run(some_variable)
> ```

However I keep getting the error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'save/RestoreV2_20': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

> available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0

It suggest that you should use the server you created. Try passing `server.target` when creating the session.

```
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
    print sess.run(some_variable)
```

Comment: you would still need to filter for a task-index

Comment: This works only with non-chief workers (for example using the filter 'if FLAGS.task_index == 1'). 
However, when I do that with chief worker ('if FLAGS.task_index == 0'), it keeps waiting for responses from other workers..